# Gluon mobile apps: How to clean up temp files on application exit?

Tags: gluon-mobile

My application writes some temporary files to its private storage.
The application currently uses `LifecycleService` + `LifecycleEvent.PAUSE` to do the clean up of these files.

Is there a way to detect if the app is closed (swiped off) on the mobile device, so that the clean up could me moved there ?